# ValueError: Variable mlp-fc/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable()

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I implemented multi-layer perceptrons (MLP) with one hidden layer using TensorFlow and got the following error when calling the function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def MLP(x, option, dropout=1, prefix ='', num_outputs=1, reuse=None):
      weights = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.001, 0.001)
      biases = tf.constant_initializer(0.001, dtype=tf.float32)

      fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=dropout),
                       num_outputs=option.num_outputs, 
                       biases_initializer=biases,
                       weights_initializer = weights, 
                       activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, 
                       scope=prefix + 'fc', 
                       reuse=reuse)
      logits = tf.contrib.layers.linear(tf.nn.dropout(fc1, keep_prob=dropout),
                       num_outputs=num_outputs,
                       biases_initializer=biases,
                       weights_initializer = weights,
                       scope=prefix + 'l',
                       reuse=reuse)

return logits

logits = MLP(x, option, dropout=dp, prefix='mlp-', reuse=True)
```

**ValueError: Variable mlp-fc/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?**

I tried to initialize the weights and set the weights_initializer but still got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to **reuse** weights named **'mlp-fc/weights'**, which doesn't exist.

Same error may be applied for your **tf.contrib.layers.linear** also.

In order to **reuse**, you first have to define them.

However, if you don't want to **reuse** any variable weights, you can simply remove **reuse= True** from both methods, **tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected** and **tf.contrib.layers.linear**.

**EDIT**

You may use something similar to the following code.

```
with tf.variable_scope("mlp-fc"):
    #add a new variable to the graph
    var=tf.get_variable("weights",shape)
```

You can follow this article to https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/variable-sharing-in-tensorflow/ to understand more about **reuse**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Nipun. I tried initializing the weights and set the weights_initializer but still got the same error. Could you help define them? I want to reuse weights.